# C# while loop not exiting (quicksort)

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, quicksort

for some reason, my while loop for (i<=j) does not end when j goes lower than i.

I watched the debug values, and have repeatedly seen values of (4,3), (6,5) etc for i and j (respectively).

```
public static List<Item> QuickSort(List<Item> a, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    double pivotValue = ((left + right) / 2);
    Item x = a[Convert.ToInt32(pivotValue)];
    Item w;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        //these while loops continue looping after i<=j is false
        while (a[i] < x)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (x < a[j])
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j)
        {
            w = a[i];
            a[i++] = a[j];
            a[j--] = w;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
    {
        QuickSort(a, left, j);
    }
    if (i < right)
    {
        QuickSort(a, i, right);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe `while` is broken. Keep debugging. Maybe it's the recursion?

Comment: It never gets to the recursion.  this happens on the first pass.

Comment: Is Item a user-defined class? If so, can you provide the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet it's either the recursion or one of the internal while loops that's still going on.  I don't have the quicksort algorithm memorized, but I'd wager that if you broke in the debugger you'd find yourself in one of the two inner while loops.

Comment: Except that `a[pivotValue]` is guaranteed to break these inner loops since it is not greater or less than itself (when `i` or `j` equals `pivotValue`)

Comment: it does keep looping through the  (a[i] < x) loop, after the i++ has raised i past j

also this happens on the first pass, no recursion yet.

Comment: and what value does x have?

Answer (score 0):

Coding quicksort is a very good exercice, it's not as easy as it may look to get everything right! ;)

Here's one problem with your code. Consider what happens if `j` bumps into the pivot, while `i` does not. You exchange the pivot (at `j`) with the value at `i` and increment `i` past the pivot. This cannot continue correctly (if you understand Quicksort you should understand why).

After choosing the pivot, I like to exchange it with one bound (either `left` or `right`), go exchange values until `i` and `j` meet and then put the pivot back at this place. There are other ways, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a infinite loop.

```
while (a[i] < x)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

If x is the largest number in the list, it will raise 'i' as long as the array is out of Range, and the programm will throw a OutOfRangeException.

Comment: This does not explain everything... since `i` starts equal to `left` and `left <= pivot` by construction, `while(a[i] < x) i++` will increase `i` up to the pivot at worse.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if `i==j` **and** `a[i]==x`...? No increment, no decrement, just swap and continue...

Consider changing `while(i<=j)` to `while(i<j)`. Also swap is not necessary if `i==j`...